# geting id value of input text in java script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

how can I get the value using this id i generated in javascript.

```
echo '<td><input type=text id=hello'.$i.' name=hello data-id='.$fet["username"].' onchange=loadXMLDoc1(this.value,this,"hello"); value='.$fet["username"].'></td>';
```

Comment: Get the value from code running where? How is this related to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

assuming i=1,

```
document.getElementById("hello1").value
```

assuming you want it dynamically:

```
document.getElementById("hello<?=$i?>").value
```

EDIT:
sometimes you don't have short_tag on in PHP, and then you'd use

```
document.getElementById("hello<?php echo $i;?>").value
```

Comment: how to get dynamically

Comment: document.getElementById("hello<?=$i?>").value

Comment: @user3386779 you can get value of any variable by useing `<?php ?>` in jquery

Comment: function loadXMLDoc2(a)
{
var u=document.getElementById("hello<?php echo =$i;?>").value;
alert("u"+u);
}
    while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {
        
        echo '<tr onchange=loadXMLDoc2(this)>';
        echo '<td><input type=text id=hello'.$i.' name=hello data-id='.$fet["username"].' onchange=fun(); value='.$fet["username"].'>';
      echo '<td><input type=text id=uid'.$i.' name=uid onchange=loadXMLDoc1(this.value,this,"uid") value='.$fet["id"].'>';
       echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
        }